# Make qr code full width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using [this](http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/) library to make QR codes.

I'm trying to give the qrcode a width of 100%. I've tried using `style="width: 100% !important;"` like I would on images, but it doesn't worked.

([codepen Reference Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMoLgb))

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the outcome you are having with that code?
Also, please post the full relevant code, as it is, it's really difficult to help you with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your codepen it work with width 100% on the image

```
img {width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi refer add css for image:

```
#qrcode img{
 width: 100%;
}
```